# Python - How to delete the last element in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this:

```
listadr = [[a, b], [1, 2]]
```

How to remove the last entry of the last list to have this result ?

```
result = [[a, b], [1]]
```

I have tried

```
for adr in listadr:
   for adr[1] in adr:
      del adr[-1]
```

But this code delete also 'b' ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete only the last element's last element, like this

```
listadr = [['a', 'b'], [1, 2]]
del listadr[-1][-1]
print(listadr)
# [['a', 'b'], [1]]
```

`listadr[-1]` will get the last element of `listadr` and `listadr[-1][-1]` will get the last element of the last element of `listadr` and kill it with `del`.

Alternatively, you can do

```
listadr[-1] = listadr[-1][:-1]
```

This would be replacing the last element of `listadr` with the last element of `listadr` excluding its last element. `listadr[-1][:-1]` means get all the elements till the last element of the last element of `listadr`.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to loop here, simply index the list using `[-1][-1]`:

```
>>> listadr = [['a', 'b'], [1, 2]]
>>> del listadr[-1][-1]
>>> listadr
[['a', 'b'], [1]]
```

If you want the item as well then use `list.pop()` on last sublist:

```
>>> listadr = [['a', 'b'], [1, 2]]
>>> listadr[-1].pop()
2
>>> listadr
[['a', 'b'], [1]]
```